# Check which object are colliding with camera view frustum

Tags: performance, view, game-engine, frustum

I am trying to optimize game.

In my game I have more than 100k 2D objects (e.g. circles and rectangles).

My camera can see just couple of them - 10-20 (depends on object size).

In my update loop I am checking what object’a bounding box collide with camera blinding box. All colliding objects are then used for further computation and actions.

Problem is, that every update loop in foreach I am checking collision for all 100k object, which is a performance bottleneck.

I cannot come up with some optimization, which would increase performance.

Thanks